# Fixing : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

I'm a beginner to java and I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now. The program is a sleep calculator that uses a GUI in IntelliJ.

```
at SleepCalculator$1.<init>(SleepCalculator.java:32)
at SleepCalculator.<init>(SleepCalculator.java:31)
at SleepCalculator.main(SleepCalculator.java:131)
```

The errors show up here and the code for them is this:

```
31->  BtnCalc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
32->     int one = Integer.parseInt(TxtYear.getText());
        int two = Integer.parseInt(TxtYearB.getText());

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SleepCalculator");
131->   frame.setContentPane(new SleepCalculator().Sleep);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This problem has been showing up on my other programs and nothing I have tried has fixed it.

Comment: The empty string doesn't contains integer, so the exception raised. Add a try catch block that wraps integer.parseInt.

Comment: Alright , thank you so much I'll try that!!